# Xamarin Forms iOS NullReferenceException on navigating back

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an app for Android and iOS.
The first month of this project I couldn't test it on iOS because of the lack of proper equipment, so I proceeded in the darkness.

Now I'm able to run the app on iOS and at first, it seems to work, but when the navigation back button is pressed a **null exception** is thrown in the Main class,

If I run Navigation.PopAsync instead it kind of works. No error is thrown, but it will not be possible to access the same page with Navigation.PushAsync again.

The issue happens on every page of the solution with a back button.

All the packages are up to date.

The app contains tabbed pages and navigation.

I cleaned the solution and rebuild it.

I started a similar project for testing, and it worked perfectly. If I cannot find a solution for this issue I will try to begin a new one from scratch.

Main:

```
public class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();


    Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init("AIzaSyAf7cZszmKjY23XGn8JMWqd7xAU60_vHWs");


        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

Installed Nuggets:

[image]

Comment: what does the stack trace show?

Comment: Its probably something else what xamarin forms version are you on?

Comment: Thank you guys you gave me some insights, turns out the error was in another part, a custom entry renderer, I read the stack trace carefully and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of a Custom Renderer of an entry.

I had a `Element.PropertyChanged +=` out of the `if(e.OldElement == null)`condition.

Just placing it inside the condition solved it all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The issue was in a *custom renderer*. I solved it by putting everything inside an *if* statement.

```
if (Control != null) { 
    // Your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to navigation and is fixed like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FlyoutPage()); });
```

Solved issue.